# How to create a nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Hello all just learning dictionary in python. I have few data please let me know how to create a nested dictionary. Data are available below with duplicate values in excel file. Please do explain using for loop

```
Name   Account Dept

John   AC     Lab1
Dev    AC     Lab1
Dilip  AC     Lab1,Lab2
Sat    AC     Lab1,Lab2
Dina   AC     Lab3
Surez  AC     Lab4
```

I need the result in below format:

```
{
   'AC': {
      'Lab1': ['John', 'Dev', 'Dilip', 'Sat'],
      'Lab2': ['Dilip','Sat'],
      'Lab3': ['Dina'],
      'Lab4': ['Surez']
   }
}
```

Comment: How have _you_ tried to solve this? Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service; we only help with _specific_ issues in existing code.

Comment: As far as I got with pandas `df.pop('Dept').str.split(',').explode().to_frame().join(df).set_index(['Account', 'Dept'])`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should get you closer to an answer but I'd need your input file to optimize it:

```
import xlrd
from collections import defaultdict

wb = xlrd.open_workbook("<your filename>")

sheet_names = wb.sheet_names()
sheet = wb.sheet_by_name(sheet_names[0])

d = defaultdict(defaultdict(list))

for row_idx in range(0, sheet.nrows):
    cell_obj_0 = sheet.cell(row_idx, 0)
    cell_obj_1 = sheet.cell(row_idx, 1)
    cell_obj_2 = sheet.cell(row_idx, 2)
    for lab in cell_obj_2.split(","):
        d[cell_obj_1][lab].append(cell_obj_0)
```

Comment: Yeah this should do it. I didn't see the data was in an excel file :P. Time for bed.